# Проброс порта C# Renci SSH.NET

Tags: c#, .net, ssh

Пытаюсь написать аналог команд в VS2015.
`putty.exe -ssh  -C -L 1111:myhost:3389 admin@server.com -P 1000 -pw "1234"`
`mstsc /v:localhost:1111 /f`

Если запустить команды через cmd, то все работает. Дальше я успешно подключаюсь к удаленному рабочему столу. Написал что-то подобное на C# с использованием билиотеки Renci SSH.NET, но ничего не сработало.

Как это реализовать?

Функция в VS:

```
public void sshConnect(string IP_ssh_server, int port_ssh_server, string ssh_user, string ssh_password)
{
    PasswordConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new PasswordConnectionInfo(IP_ssh_server, port_ssh_server, ssh_user, ssh_password);
    connectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    using (var client = new SshClient(connectionInfo))
    {
        try
        {
            client.Connect();
            ForwardedPortLocal localPort = new ForwardedPortLocal(1111, "myhost", 3389);
            client.AddForwardedPort(localPort);
            localPort.Start();
            if (client.IsConnected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SSH connection active");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SSH connection NOTactive");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S.

Как узнать, что порт проброшен и соединение держится?

Результат работы консоли:

```
SSH connection active
Поток 0x20b8 завершился с кодом 0 (0x0).
Поток 0x26dc завершился с кодом 0 (0x0).
```

Как понять завершение потоков как-то связано с моей функцией?

Comment: Завершение потоков никак не связано с вашей функцией, она однопоточная.

Comment: Как я понял, это Windows Forms, используйте `Debug.WriteLine` вместо `Console.WriteLine`, работает так же, но в некоторых случаях второй вариант может выбросить исключение, если выводящий поток не будет захвачен студией, а первый просто работает только в отладке, где он вам и нужен. `using System.Diagnostics;`